# Como pasar variables entre métodos de una clase Java

Tags: java, clase, método

estuve buscando por Internet pero sólo encontré casos ya avanzados, el problema es que estoy haciendo un programa que compara tres números y en el caso de que sean los 2 primeros iguales pues hace una llamada desde el método principal (static void main) a otro método pasando las variables para trabajar con ellas en el otro, pero no me salen más que errores.

este es el código que estoy intentando hacer, mi idea era poner las variables como globales para luego usarlas en cualquier método dentro de la clase ComparadorAvanzado, pero no va.

```
package comparadoravanzado;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComparadorAvanzado {
    int n1;
    int mayor;

    public void iguales () {
        this.mayor=n1;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ComparadorAvanzado Propiedades= new ComparadorAvanzado();
        Scanner entradaTeclado = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número: ");
        this.n1=entradaTeclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el segundo número: ");
        this.n2=entradaTeclado.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Introduzca el tercer número: ");
        this.n3=entradaTeclado.nextInt();

        if (n1>n2) {
            mayor=n1;
            menor=n2;
            if (n1>n3) {
                mayor=n1;
            }
            else {
                mayor=n3;
            }
        }
        else if (n1==n2) {
            igual1=n1;
            igual2=n2;
            if (n2>n3) {
                mayor=n1;
                mayor2=n2;
                Propiedades.iguales(n1, mayor);
            }
            else {
                mayor=n3;
            }
        }
        else {
            mayor=n2;
            menor=n1;
            if (n2>n3) {
                mayor=n2;
            }
            else {
                mayor=n3;
            }
        }

        if (n3>mayor) {
            mayor=n3;
        }
        else {
            if (n3<menor) {
                menor=n3;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("El más grande es "+mayor+" y el más pequeño es "+menor);
    }

}
```

También intenté declarar tanto las variables como parámetros en el static void main y luego en la llamada al método iguales como parámetros de entrada y luego dentro de iguales, pero no es nada rentable hacerlo así.

```
public static void main(String[] args, int n1, int n2, int mayor, int menor, int igual1, int menor)     //en el método principal

...
Propiedades.iguales(n1, n2, mayor, menor, igual1, menor);  //en la llamada al método


public void iguales(int n1, int n2...)     //en el método "iguales"
```

Comment: lo que puedes hacer es declararte una variable estatica de tipo vector para que almacenes toda las variables que desees pasar su valor hacia otro lado. asi el valor no cambiara porque sera static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantos conceptos básicos un poco perdidos que tienes que tratar de esclarecer antes de pasar a ejercicios de este tipo:

- **No puedes asignar un valor a una variable no declarada.**

Cuando haces `this.n1=entradaTeclado.nextInt();` estás haciendo referencia a una variable que no está declarada en el contexto que le estás indicando, ya que dentro del método `main()` no existe ninguna variable `n1` puesto que la tienes declarada más arriba. Para poder acceder a ese `n1` podrías hacerlo a través del objeto de clase que has instanciado `Propiedades.n1` pero creo que te estás complicando demasiado, no te hace falta tenerla declarada como atributo de la clase.

Las variables `n2, n3, menor, igual1, igual2, mayor2` ni siquiera las tienes declaradas fuera de ámbito, no aparecen en ningún lado más de tu código salvo en el momento que las usas para darles valor. Han de ser declaradas correctamente.

- **Llamada a un método público desde una función estática**

Para poder llamar a `iguales()` esta debe ser estática.

- **Llamada a un método pasándole unos parámetros de entrada que no están definidos en su constructor.**

Si a la función `iguales()` le quieres pasar dos números han de estar declarados en el constructor de dicha función `static void iguales (int mayor, int n1)`.

Seguro que hay más cosas que se me escapan o algo que no haya hecho del todo correcto, no soy especialista en Java pero al menos esto debería de orientarte un poco.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ComparadorAvanzado {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int mayor = 0;
        int menor = 0;

        Scanner entradaTeclado = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Introduzca el primer número: ");
        int n1 = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el segundo número: ");
        int n2 = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Introduzca el tercer número: ");
        int n3 = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

        if (n1 > n2) {
            mayor = n1;
            menor = n2;

            if (n1 > n3) {
                mayor = n1;
            }
            else {
                mayor = n3;
            }
        }
        else if (n1 == n2) {
            int igual1 = n1;
            int igual2 = n2;
            if (n2 > n3) {
                mayor = n1;
                int mayor2 = n2;
                iguales(mayor, n1);
            }
            else {
                mayor = n3;
            }
        }
        else {
            mayor = n2;
            menor = n1;
            if (n2 > n3) {
                mayor = n2;
            }
            else {
                mayor = n3;
            }
        }

        if (n3 > mayor) {
            mayor = n3;
        }
        else {
            if (n3<menor) {
                menor = n3;
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        System.out.println("El más grande es " + mayor + " y el más pequeño es " + menor);
    }

    static void iguales (int mayor, int n1) {
       mayor = n1;
    }

}
```

Comment: No me he metido en como está la estructura de `if` en donde realizas las comparaciones para ver que número es mayor y cual es menor. Creo que existen un par de casos que no has contemplado y en que la variable `menor` queda sin un número asignado, pero eso ya es cosa de que te pegues un poco contra tu código para sacarlo.